# How can I verify the output of this method using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, moq

I have an MVC3 app and I've got a Register ActionMethod on the AccountController. When a user registers I want it to email them their user details. I'm using [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) (for the first time) and want to run a unit test that verifies that the Send method gets called and that I've called the Register email template.

Here is the section of code in my Register ActionMethod that calls the email tempalte:

```
dynamic email = new Email("Register");
email.To = model.Email;
_emailService.Send(email);
```

_emailService is of type IEmailService. I'm using Moq and know how to verify a method has been called but in this instance I'm passing an Email object into Send. So I don't know if I create a Mock or whether the Email object used on the Register controller is what I should be testing. I'm also not sure on the best way to test the 'output' of the email or to at least verify that the 'Register' template in the Views/Emails folder is called. Here's my test so far:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void register_post_success_sends_email_with_account_details()
    {
        // Arrange
        // fakeMembers contains a List<Member> repository of 5 fake Members which I 
        // use to ensure the Register completes and then steps into the code 
        // that calls the email code authentication code
        FakeMembers fakeMembers = new FakeMembers();
        _mockMemberRepository.Setup(x => x.GetMembers()).Returns(fakeMembers.Members);
        _mockEmailService.Setup(e => e.Send(?? what do I place here??));
        // set up of emailService.Send is a void method so do I just not use Returns?

        //// Arrange
        Member model = new Member()
        {
            Email = "member6@mydomain.com",
            Password = "test123",
            ConfirmPassword = "test123"
        };
        Mock<Email> mockEmail = new Mock<Email>();
        // Act
        var result = _controller.Register(model);

        // Assert
        // Do I use a mockEmail.Object here? I want to test the Email called on the 
        // Register ActionMethod?

        // Test Send method was called ONCE
        _mockEmailService.Verify(e => e.Send(mockEmail.Object), Times.Once());

        //Test either the output of the Email that was sent OR check that it was the
        //Register email template that was called
    }
```

I hope I've been concise enough and someone can help

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `Setup` on a method that has no return. Since by the looks `Email` is just a data structure there is no need to mock it. Besides since it get new'ed up inside the controller it is best to verify the object passed into `Send` has the properties I expect using `It.Is<>` syntax.

```
[TestMethod]
public void register_post_success_sends_email_with_account_details()
{
    //// Arrange
    FakeMembers fakeMembers = new FakeMembers();
    _mockMemberRepository.Setup(x => x.GetMembers()).Returns(fakeMembers.Members);

    Member model = new Member()
    {
        Email = "member6@mydomain.com",
        Password = "test123",
        ConfirmPassword = "test123"
    };

    //Act
    var result = _controller.Register(model);

    //Assert
    _mockEmailService.Verify(e => e.Send(It.Is<Email>(email =>
           {
               return email.To == model.Email;  // you can add more here such as the body etc
           }), Times.Once())
```

> ```
>   //Test either the output of the Email that was sent OR check that it was the
>   //Register email template that was called
> ```

As for this part I would separate into 2 tests where you know which condition will be met.